# Thread safe read/write to a counter

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

Im trying to make 2 threads that read/write to a counter using thread safe methods.

I have written some code to try test this but the read thread just reads the counter at its max (1000)

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Counter c = new Counter();

    Thread inc = new Increment(c);
    Thread read = new Read(c);

    inc.start();
    read.start();

}
```

Counter:

```
public class Counter {

private int count;

public Counter() {
    count = 0;
}

public synchronized void increment() {
    count++;
}

public synchronized int getVal() {
    return count;
}

}
```

Increment:

```
public class Increment extends Thread {

private static final int MAX = 1000;
private Counter myCounter;

public Increment(Counter c) {
    myCounter = c;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        myCounter.increment();
    }
}
}
```

Read:

```
public class Read extends Thread {

private static final int MAX = 1000;
private Counter myCounter;

public Read(Counter c) {
    myCounter = c;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        System.out.println(myCounter.getVal());
    }
}
}
```

Would I be better off using Atomic Integer to hold the value of the counter to allow me to safely increment it and get the value?

Comment: Yes, but that's because your current solution uses method-level synchronization. If a thread is currently accessing `increment` then another thread is not blocked from accessing `getVal` at the same time. Another solution could be wrapping both method bodies in `synchronized(this) {}` blocks

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke another thread will be blocked on any `synchronized` block of code, as that thread will not be the owner of the object's implicit lock.

Comment: Pardon, but doesn't the fact that Read just reads the MAX value mean that the threads _are_  synchronized? While Increment is accessing c no other thread can access it, so the Read thread reads c only when Increment is done writing it.

Comment: Try upping your MAX to something substantial (`1_000_000_000`) and you should see some thread interleaving. Counting to 1000 is no effort. You could add `wait()` and `notify()` if you want the reader to read as soon as something has been written (incremented), and yes using AtomicInteger is a nicer solution.

Comment: _"it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object."_ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: @diginoise it appears you are correct

Comment: @diginoise Thanks for that. How could I go about implementing wait and notify?

Comment: Correction to my own comment: lock is released after synchronized _method_ is done, not after _thread_ is done. So yes, they should alternate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want interleave execution of **Read** thread and **Increment** thread  much more often then the natural operating system thread pre-emption, just make each thread give up their lock (by calling `<lockedObject>.wait()` followed by `<lockedObject>.notify()` or `notifyAll()` in the respective `run()` methods:

[In Reader]:

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        synchronized (myCounter) {
            System.out.println(myCounter.getVal());
            try {
                myCounter.wait(0L, 1);
                myCounter.notifyAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[In Increment]:

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        synchronized (myCounter) {
            myCounter.increment();
            try {
                myCounter.wait(0L, 1);
                myCounter.notifyAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upping the `MAX` constant to `1_000_000_000` (1 billion) made the treads interleave as well every now and then (on my machine interleave happened just by gazing at few printouts between **150** and **400_000** iterations).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `Read` and `Increment` are independent and do not stall. Each main loop progresses to MAX without the other. You remove any Read thread altogether and Increment will count to MAX. You can make Read sleep() for some per iteration will make it read non-continuous increments. Please (re) test.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is perfectly fine as is. It just so happened that your increment thread finished all its increments before the read thread got a chance to read. 1,000 increments takes almost no time at all.

Comment: Exactly. Try adding a delay in Counter.increment(), you will see that while the counter is being written no one will be reading.